# How to maintain parent & child work item while importing csv file

Tags: rational-team-concert

I have created a csv file with parent and child work item (eg: Parent work item is Milestone and Child work item is Task i.e., Requirement 1 is a Milestone and Requirement 1.1 Task, Requirement 1.2 Task are Child of Requirement 1). I need to maintain parent and child link at the time of uploading .csv file for creating work items. Please do suggest some ways to maintain parent and child link at the time of uploading .csv file.